where to apply the filtering in the service repository pattern
I have userRepository, userService and userController and I want to filter users on the basis of the email and I am using prisma with postgresql, where can I filter. In future I would also like to filter the user on the basis of the account creation date or number of posts posted.
userRepository:
@injectable()
export class UserRepositoryPrisma implements UserRepository {
  constructor(@inject('PrismaClient') private prisma: PrismaClient) {}

  async getAll(filter?: object): Promise<User[]> {
    const whereClause = filter ?? {};

    return this.prisma.user.findMany({
      where: whereClause,
    });
  }

userService:
@injectable()
export class UserService implements IUserService {
  constructor(
    @inject('UserRepository') private userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {}

  getAll(filter?: object): Promise<User[]> {
    const whereClause = filter ?? {};
    return this.userRepository.getAll(whereClause);
  }

controller:
there will be query for some fields like:
http://localhost:3000/api/users?email=abc@gmail.com&accountCreated=gt[somedate]

router.get(
  '/',
  handleAsync(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const users = await userService.getAll();

    if (!users.length) return next(new AppError(404, `No users found.`));

    res.status(200).json({
      results: users.length,
      data: {
        users,
      },
    });
  }),
);

What is the best practice.

What do you mean by "where to apply the filtering"?

I mean where can I apply filtering to the database like writing the prisma filters, in the service, repo or controller layer.

Depends on your needs, you can place them anywhere, even accept them as parameters from the client? But typically the service would expose different methods for different things.
